# Asking for longest side of a triangle c

Tags: c, geometry

I am trying to get my program to print out the longest side of the triangle but I seem to be getting the else and if statements incorrect how can I fix the issues and what am I doing wrong.

```
            if (a >= b && a >= c)
    printf("A is the largest side.", a);

if (b >= a && b >= c)
    printf("B is the largest side.", b);

if (c >= a && c >= b)
    printf("C is the largest side.", c);

else if (a <= b && a <= c)
    printf("A is the smallest side.", a);

else if (b <= a && b <= c)
    printf("B is the smallest side.", b);

else if (c <= a && c <= b)
    printf("C is the smallest side.", c);
```

Comment: `if (a == a > b && c)` is nonsense. You probably meant `if (a > b && a > c)`

Comment: Don't forget the boundary case where two or three sides are the same length.

Comment: `else b < a || c;` And what is that? `else` doesn't take a condition and that statement after the `else` is a noop.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will be better than your if-sequence

adopt it a bit, for your purposes

```
int main(){
    char longest_side;
    int a, b, c;
    longest_side = (a > b) ? ((a > c) ? ('a') : ('c')) : ((b > c) ? ('b') : ('c'));
    retrun 0;
}
```

---

if you want to leave your own code, change it to this

```
if (a > b && a > c)
    printf("A is the largest side.", a);    
else if (b > a && b > c)
    printf("B is the largest side.", b);    
else
    printf("C is the largest side.", c);

if (a < b && a < c)
    printf("A is the smallest side.", a);    
else if (b < a && b < c)
    printf("B is the smallest side.", b);
else 
    printf("C is the smallest side.", c);
```

also notice that your  `printf call doesn't output your side length`, cause you use `"%d"` nowhere.

```
printf("C is the smallest side. Length: %d", c);
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy approach to find the max number IMHO:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int max(int x, int y)
{
    if (x > y) return x;
    else return y;
}

int main(void)
{
    int a, b, c;
    a = 10; b = 20; c = 30;

    printf("%d\n", max(max(a, b), c));
}
```

I am sure you can pick up from here.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can try this. Here you can get some pretty solution to find max and min with if-else with function

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int max(int a, int b)
{
    return 0.5 * (a + b + fabs(a - b));
}

int min(int a, int b)
{
    return 0.5 * (a + b - fabs(a - b));
}

int main(void)
{
    int a, b, c;

    scanf("%d %d %d", &a, &b, &c);

    if(a == max(max(a, b), c))
        printf("A is the largest side. And it\'s value is: %d\n", a);
    else if(b == max(max(a, b), c))
        printf("B is the largest side. And it\'s value is: %d\n", b);
    else
        printf("C is the largest side. And it\'s value is: %d\n", c);

    if(a == min(min(a, b), c))
        printf("A is the smallest side. And it\'s value is: %d\n", a);
    else if(b == min(min(a, b), c))
        printf("B is the smallest side. And it\'s value is: %d\n", b);
    else
        printf("C is the smallest side. And it\'s value is: %d\n", c);

    return 0;
}
```